# Deserialize JSON into C# Object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a json object into c# object but couldnt do it. Here is my json object that I sending

```
{
    "User_":
    {
        "Email":"test@test.com",
        "Password":"pass1"
    }
}
```

here is my c# classes that I use

```
public class User_
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

public class User_
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

```
public class RootObject
{
    public User_ User_ { get; set; }
}
```

here is the code that I use to deserialize

```
RootObject request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json.ToString());
```

This code creates a User_ object but Email and Password fields are null. What am I doing wrong here?

While I was debugging, I saw what is coming

```
{{ "{\"Email_\":\"test@test.com\",\"Password_\":\"pass1\"}": ""  }}
```

It looks weird

Comment: You should deserialize to `RootObject` instead. And you need to change the name of the property to match the one in the json (or the other way around) And class `User_` should probably be `User`

Comment: Have you tried http://json2csharp.com?

Comment: Please create a [mcve], as right now your json *does* deserialize into your objects. In other words, your code seems to work as you want it to.

Comment: For instance, you edited your question to deserialize into `RootObject` instead of `User_`. **Did that fix your issue?** If so, then most probably it was the incorrect thing to do, since if that fixed your question you probably should delete the question as it no longer makes any sense.

Comment: @OP You shouldn't edit your question to work after you've posted broken code.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen no it didnt work

Comment: Then please post your *actual* code as the code you've posted in the question *does work*.

Comment: @Arif The code as you have posted in your question [does work](https://rextester.com/HOPDS18924). As I said: you shouldn't edit your question to the solution because it means your question no longer makes any sense, and renders the answers invalid.

Comment: I like the fuzz of Json/C# question, every one comming with a new "Json2CSharp", "Same code same thing". Either it's a dupe, a typo or need an MCVE. We don't need so many answer.

Comment: The json in your screenshot does not match the json in your question.

Comment: You have a JSON string as a key in a JSON object, it would seem.

Comment: To be honest, that doesn't look like valid json. An object inside an object, I'm not sure that is legal.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, It is valid ! It's the root object serialise as a property that has string empty as value. everything is escape seems unpratical but valid

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen , but why does the json come like that. it is valid.

Comment: @ArifYILMAZ, Do you have server side code or do you really have to play with this ?

Comment: No, this is not valid json, `{{ ... }}` is not valid json. Could it be that the debugger is doubling up those braces? What you have is this: `{{ "key": "" }}`, where `key` here is json in a string.

Comment: Couple of questions. What type is `json` in that code? I know `json.ToString()` is a string, but what is `json`? Also, can you do something like `Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());` and then copy that output to us? I want to make sure that we're not seeing things that the debugger is adding "for convenience".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do this, I get the correct values of `Email` and `Password`:

```
public class User_
  {
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
  }

  public class RootObject
  {
    public User_ User_ { get; set; }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string jsonString = "{\"User_\":{\"Email\":\"test@test.com\",\"Password\":\"pass1\"}}";
      RootObject request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine("Email: {0}", request.User_.Email);
      Console.WriteLine("Password: {0}", request.User_.Password);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

You can see it working [**HERE**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GQug66)

Comment: While I am debugging, I receive this {{ "{\"Email_\":\"test@test.com\",\"Password_\":\"pass1\"}": ""  }}

Comment: @ArifYILMAZ, so the `json` is not well formatted. That's why it fails in your program.

Answer (score 1):

When deserializing object of a class directly, The class name is not required in JSON. If you are on the other hand deserializing the JSON given above, then deserialize using RootObject

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json.ToString()).User_;
```

with

```
public class RootObject
{
    public User_ User_ { get; set; }
}
```

OR

Deserialize the following JSON instead:

```
    {
        "Email":"test@test.com",
        "Password":"pass1"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use **`[JsonProperty("KeyName")]`** when your key names are not pure alphabets.

**`[JsonProperty("KeyName")]`** provide you an advantage of deserializing such json that contains some keys like

- User_
- User$
- @User
- *User&

And many more

Just add this attribute to your class property like

```
[JsonProperty("User_")]
public User User { get; set; }
```

And this makes your property name keep simple and more readable

So finally for your json

```
{
    "User_":
    {
        "Email_":"test@test.com",
        "Password_":"pass1"
    }
}
```

All classes after adding `JsonProperty` look like

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("User_")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("Email_")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Password_")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
RootObject request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json.ToString());

Console.WriteLine(request.User.Email);
Console.WriteLine(request.User.Password);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have 2 issues in your c# class

1. In your `RootObject` class you have to use

   ```cs
   public User_ User{get;set;}
   ```
2. When you seralize Json you have to use.

   ```cs
   User_ request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json.ToString());
   ```

This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code.

```
public class User_
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public User_ User { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize operation:

```
RootObject request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that your RootObject is serialise as the property name of a new object with string empty as value. The result of to many serialisation server side.

And you can handle those easly, the Following class will work only for this exact Json response once the password/email change you will need a new one.

```
public partial class DontDoThis
{
    [JsonProperty("{\"Email_\":\"test@test.com\",\"Password_\":\"pass1\"}")]
    public string EmailTestTestComPasswordPass1 { get; set; }
}
```

In order to fix this you are left with:
 - Change the code server side to provide correct result.
 - String manipulation to remove and un escape the result.
 - Deserialise once in   and  deseriliase again.